# Compare dataframe row-wise in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in python and would like to select rows where col2 has 'MSH' and 'MDR' for the identical col1 values and store it in a dataframe.

```
col1  col2  col3
C1234 MSH   fever
C1234 MDR   fieber
C4566 MSF   malaria
```

The expected output is:

```
col1  col2  col3
C1234 MSH   fever
C1234 MDR   fieber
```

I have created a dictionary using below line of code. However, is there a way to do it on a dataframe level.

```
terms = {k: [g['col2'].tolist(), g['col3'].tolist()] for k,g in df.groupby('col1')}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need select if only `MSH, MDR` values per group? Or possible multiple values like `MSH, MDR, MMM` per group and then need select?

Comment: MSH, MDR values per group. There could be multiple values for 'MSH' or 'MDR' per col1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create sets and compare if greater or equal values per groups - then are selected groups also if contains another value(s):

```
print (df)
    col1 col2     col3
0  C1234  MSH    fever
1  C1234  MDR   fieber
2  C1234  MSF  malaria
3  C4566  MSH    fever
4  C4566  MDR   fieber
5  C4567  MDR  malaria

s = set(['MSH','MDR'])
df1 = df[df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= s)]
print (df1)
    col1 col2     col3
0  C1234  MSH    fever
1  C1234  MDR   fieber
2  C1234  MSF  malaria
3  C4566  MSH    fever
4  C4566  MDR   fieber
```

Or compare if unique values per groups has only values from set by equal:

```
s = set(['MSH','MDR'])
df2 = df[df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == s)]
print (df2)
    col1 col2    col3
3  C4566  MSH   fever
4  C4566  MDR  fieber
```